# MVC3, RequireHttps and custom handler result in http 310

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, https

I'm trying to build a web application that uses an SSL connection. So I did some research and found out that I could use the RequireHttpsAttribute class to achieve what I needed. Thing is that when I use it, the execution of the application results in an 310 error(too many redirections). I even built a custom class to handle the switch from http to https. But that too results in an error.

My Class to handle te protocol switch:

```
Public Class RequireSSLAttribute
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute

    Public Property IsRequired() As Boolean

    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As ActionExecutingContext)
        If Me.IsRequired AndAlso filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme <> "https" Then
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.OriginalString.Replace("http:", "https:").Remove(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.OriginalString.LastIndexOf(":") + 1), True)
            filterContext.Result = New HttpUnauthorizedResult
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        IsRequired = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know who your host is, but I just ran into a similar problem on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) and discovered this in their [knowledge base](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/ssl-and-certificates):

> If you're using the built-in RequireHttpsAttribute to ensure that a
>   controller action always uses HTTPS you will experience a redirect
>   loop. The reason is that SSL is terminated at the load balancer level
>   and RequireHttps doesn't recognize the X-Forwarded-Proto header it
>   uses to indicate that the request was made using HTTPS. You should
>   therefore use a custom RequireHttps attribute for this purpose.

They have also provided an example solution on Github [here](https://gist.github.com/915869), which I will copy below for convenience:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RequireHttpsAttributeBase = System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute;

namespace AppHarbor.Web
{
    [AttributeUsage(
        AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method,
        Inherited = true,
        AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class RequireHttpsAttribute : RequireHttpsAttributeBase
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"],
                "https",
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
            {
                return;
            }

            HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem; but perhaps even if you aren't using AppHarbor the root cause may be the same for you, in which case the above seems worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for posting. This worked for Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Does the order of these three matters?

if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection), if (string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"], "https", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)), if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal). And why do I need to have if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection) and if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal) at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
If Me.IsRequired AndAlso filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme <> "https" Then
    secureUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.OriginalString.Replace("http:", "https:").Remove(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.OriginalString.LastIndexOf(":") + 1)
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(secureUrl)
End If
```

Comment: It unfornately doesnt work, but I dont think its the actual redirecting. But it shouldn't go past the If ... then clause when accessed through https.

Comment: Is it still doing the infinite redirection? Also do you have any AuthorizationFilters as well?

Comment: For the login controller, which is the first controller, I dont have any authorization filters. The controller behind the login however uses those filters. But you can not reach it before logging on, at least I hope.

Comment: Run this while keeping the Fiddler on and see what Urls it gets redirected to.